# Print fastest test in conslose with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I can print the slowest test with `--durations=1`.
But how can i print the fastest?
I think the answer is related to terminal summary. But i need acceess to test duration somehow. I found this code in similar question, but it does not work.

```
def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    for reps in terminalreporter.stats.values():
        for rep in reps:
            if rep.when == "call":
                print("duration reported after all tests passed:", rep.nodeid, rep.duration)
```

I get an error `AttributeError: 'WarningReport' object has no attribute 'when'`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself:

```
def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    time_value = []
    for reps in terminalreporter.stats.values():
        for rep in reps:
            try:
                if rep.when == "call":
                    time_value.append((rep.nodeid, rep.duration))
            except AttributeError:
                pass
    print("Fastest test:", min(time_value, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

output:

```
Fastest test: ('tests/test_database.py::TestDatabase::test_method_5', 0.09348350000000005)
```